# Integrating custom Docset from SDKs into Xcode 10's Documentation window

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, doc

I have bundled a framework/SDK from Philips Hue written in Objective-C into my Swift project. The code of the SDK is well in-line documented. Thus, I have fired up appledoc and created a custom docset: `appledoc --project-name HueSDK --project-company Philips --install-docset .`.

The target was to implement it directly into Xcode's Documentation window: 
[image]

I have realized that this is not working anymore in Xcode 10, whereas reports show that it was working for older Xcode versions (<8). This is quite a pity as Xcode very often directs the user to the Documentation window, e.g. clicking on a link within the Quick Help Inspector:
[image]

Do you know any possibility how to integrate custom Docsets into Xcode's Documentation window?